# How to get manager property from a users request

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

The query https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id&$expand=manager does not return any information about manager!
(same result using the beta version)

Is there a solution to get the manager navigation property using the graph API ?

Comment: Hi. Did you find any answers? I want to filter by Manager. Ie) I want to get all users where I am a Manager. Anything like passing filter?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't appear that this scenario is supported at this time.

You'll have to do more than one call to get the manager property.

1) Get the list of users:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

2) [Get the manager](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_manager) per each user https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/f6672f23-134d-47a1-8da8-a0671f3cf3f3/manager

Comment: Oddly, using expand on directReports works. It is not very homogeneous!

Comment: Yes, it's very odd, especially since official documentation explicitly mentions using $expand=manager with user resource.
I've managed to get it to work using "beta" api though, you may want to try that for now.

Comment: The `beta` version can do this with `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/jon.doe@example.com?$expand=manager` . Are there any plans on integrating this into v1.0 ?

Comment: This works in v1.0: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/jon.doe@example.com/manager

Comment: Thanks Michael. I know about that one, but it just returns the manager details. Was wondering if we could get the user's data along with their manager in one go. Similar to what the above query does for the beta version.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work fine on the beta endpoint. Try the following example in the Graph Explorer https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$expand=manager
```

But some other queries don't work like expected so be careful how you use select:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$expand=manager($select=id,displayName)
```

Comment: Please provide essential details from link because link may get expired in future.

Comment: `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$expand=manager($select=id,displayName)` wont work with $select statement

Comment: Both of these things now seem to work on v1.0 as well if anyone else comes across this post later on. I couldn't find the update or documentation detailing that tho

Answer (score 2):

This feature ($expand=manager) is currently only supported in the /beta version. We hope to enable it in v1.0 later this calendar year.

Please use /beta to evaluate this new functionality and let us know your feedback.

Comment: Can [List Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-manager) be used to get a user's manager now?

Comment: Was this enabled by now? I cant seem to find information on this

Comment: Do you find something on this in 2023? thank you